# DataGrid change selectem item color in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, expression-blend

I have a DataGrid with multiple items.

In Expression Blend, how do I change the color of the row of a selected item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in your xaml only, all you need to do is override you `HighlightBrush` for your Datagrid to your selection color. Simply add this in your code inside DataGrid tag -

```
<DataGrid>
   .
   .
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                Color="Red"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   .
   .
</DataGrid>
```

`Snapshpot` with your code and resource in place (notice grid is empty since bindings not worked for me but red selection border is quite visible) -
[image: Red Selection border]